# Binomial random variable expectation bound

Tags: probability, expectation

Let $X,Y \sim \text{Bin}(n,0.5)$ for some positive $n$.

What is a lower bound for $\mathbb{E}(XY)$? When is it achieved?

My try:

I got confused by the following two results and couldn't proceed!

By Jensen's, $\mathbb{E}(XY) \geq \mathbb{E}(X)\mathbb{E}(Y)$. But we also know that $\text{cov}(X,Y)=\mathbb{E}(XY) - \mathbb{E}(X)\mathbb{E}(Y)$, and this quantity can be negative!

Please help me to proceed. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** If $\rho_{X,Y}:=\frac{\text{cov}(X,Y)}{\sigma_X\sigma_Y}$ denotes the [correlation coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlation_and_dependence) of $X,Y$, then you know that $$-1\le \rho\le 1$$
Now $\sigma_X=\sigma_Y=0.5\sqrt{n}$ and $\mathbb E[X]=\mathbb E[Y]=0.5n$. Hence, $$-1\le \rho=\frac{\mathbb E[XY]-(0.5n)^2}{\left(0.5\sqrt{n}\right)^2} \implies 0.25n(n-1)\le \mathbb E[XY]$$ The equality is attained when $\rho=-1$, for instance when $Y=n-X$ (negative linear relationship with "slope" -1).

Comment: This I know, but still, my conundrum exists (the last two statements which I have mentioned in the details)! Could you give more hints?

Comment: Thanks, but the equality attainment condition says $Y$ is negative when it is not, remember $Y\sim  \text{Bin}(n,0.5)$. Can you comment on the equality attainment again?

Comment: Also, there's a typo in the final inequality. It should be $0.25$

Comment: Hey. For the equality attainment, $Y=n-X$ suffices. :) Please check the same, and update your answer. I'll accept it.

Comment: Sorry, I was offline. You are right in both your comments, so I corrected accordingly. Thanks